# Ways to control authentication process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm trying to build an API to control the user authentication processes in Node.js, just to exercise myself, but I'm not very familiar with the resources available at a Node.js environment.

The question being: what can I use to identify an user? Only thing I can think of now are cookies, but that don't seem very safe, imho. I thought maybe there's some variable in the http request I could use.

I do not want you to list JS libraries that handle authentications for me. I wanna try to build one myself.

Comment: If this is really a learning excercise, then it's probably worth studying how other well-accepted libraries that do node auth do things and learn from them.  The most widely used library is [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), but an NPM search for ["auth"](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=auth) and ["authentication"](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=authentication) shows a lot of modules you can study.  You will likely end up using an expiring, secure cookie as your means of identifying a particular browser after authentication.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, most likely. But I really wanna understand how they work and exactly what they do, and I thought this would be a good way to do so. Maybe I should look into some article that explains authentications in depth, instead?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The way to learn what the common best practices are is to study what the most used libraries do either by studying their open source code or by finding respected articles discussion how things work.  If, once you understand the architecture you're after, you want to do your own implementation as a further learning exercise, that's fine.  But, the important first step is to study the current best practices before trying to invent your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own code as an exercise, but the mechanism the code uses to establish authentication should exactly match existing common practice in the industry. Specifically you should use a session cookie, which needs to have many very specific properties in order to be secure. Cookies are secure enough in combination with a host of other best practices (https, server hardening, security patches, etc) for most web traffic. For enhanced security this is often combined with additional password prompts before important actions (amazon, yahoo), 2-factor authentication (google, github, etc), fraud detection heuristics (facebook, banking), etc. A cookie is precisely a "variable in the http request" as you say.

Comment: Hmm. I was thinking more precisely about a variable inside the `req` (1st parameter) given to the callback function by `http.createServer()`.

Comment: Yup, that's what a session cookie is. It's an HTTP header. The value is set by the server in the response using the `Set-Cookie` header and the browser returns it in the request `Cookie` header, which is available in the node callback as `req.headers['Cookie']`.